# R function scope: want to see the return value on next iteration

Tags: r

I am trying a code a linear algebra exercise on eigenvalues, where I pass a vector to a matrix, get a another vector back, then pass that vector back again to the same matrix; I am supposed to get a steady-state value for the vector.

this is my reproducible example version of that:

```
M <- 2
v <- c(2,4,6)
c <- c()
funscope <- function(){
  c <- (M * v)/max(v)
  # want to return c and send it back in as 'v'
  #?
}
replicate(2, funscope())
```

want to get (in decimal form) these two vectors:

```
[4/6, 8/6, 12/6], [8/12, 16/12, 24,12]
```

Comment: In this example those two vectors are both `c(0.667, 1.333, 2.000)`. Is that what you want?

Comment: @MrFlick I think that is half of the assignment

Comment: I did not mean in general for the values to be the same, just that the return value would be used in the next iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative version based on your custom function and a for loop used for populating a list. You can use the C list to store results and use them for the next iterations.

```
# your function
funscope <- function(M, V){
  (M * V)/max(V)
}

# some starting params
M <- 2
V <- c(2,4,6)
C <- list()

# a foor loop to populate the list
for (i in 1:2) {
  if (i == 1) {
    C[[i]] <- funscope(M, V)  
  } else {
    C[[i]] <- funscope(M, C[[(i-1)]])
  }
}
```

Results are stored in C

```
# print to console
C

[[1]]
[1] 0.6666667 1.3333333 2.0000000

[[2]]
[1] 0.6666667 1.3333333 2.0000000
```

If you want to get them as a matrix, you can simply rbind (row-wise) or cbind (column-wise) them.

```
do.call(cbind, C) # rbind or cbind
```

Comment: This does the trick, except that when I run it, the vectors are displayed vertically, instead of horizontally:

Comment: casting the matrix multiplication result of funscope using as.vector() gives me a horizontal display of vectors as you show. Again, thanks.

Comment: I am glad you found these lines useful. You can probably use `cbind` within a `do.call` call to cast the elements of `C` into a matrix (`cbind` adds elements in a column-wise fashion; use `rbind` if you want them added line by line). Cheers! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Doing recursive iteratin like this is often easiest in a loop, but the `Reduce` function can help here too. Here's a simple wrapper to make it easier to work with in this scenario

```
iterfun <- function(f, start, N=1) {
  Reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    f(prev)
  }, rep(1, N), init=start, acc=T)[-1]
}
```

This will take a function and repeatedly perform it on itself.

If we define your function as a proper function and start out with

```
M <- 2
v <- c(2,4,6)
funscope <- function(v){
  (M * v)/max(v)
}
```

We can run it with

```
iterfun(funscope, v, N=2)
# [[1]]
# [1] 0.6666667 1.3333333 2.0000000
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 0.6666667 1.3333333 2.0000000
```

As a traditional loop, we might do

```
N <- 2
out <- vector("list", N)
x <- v
for(i in 1:N) {
    x <- funscope(x)
    out[[i]] <- x
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually one wants to stop based on a test for convergence rather than using a fixed number of iterations.  This will iterate up to `N` times stopping when the maximum difference of two successive iterations is less than `eps`.  At the end `cc` contains the value converged to, `maxabseps` contains the error and `i` contains the number of iterations run.

```
M <- 2
v <- c(2,4,6)
N <- 100 # max no of iterations
eps <- 1e-5  # abs error

c <- v
for(i in 1:N) {
   cc <- (M * c) / max(c)
   maxabsdiff <- max(abs(cc - c))
   cat(i, "maxabsdiff:", maxabsdiff, "vector:", cc, "\n")
   if (maxabsdiff < eps) break
   c <- cc
}
```

giving this output:

```
1 maxabsdiff: 4 vector: 0.6666667 1.333333 2 
2 maxabsdiff: 0 vector: 0.6666667 1.333333 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `replicate` simply repeats the expression a number of times. No information is exchanged between the different calls to `funscope`.

If you want to assign a value to a global variable (i.e. a variable *outside* of the function), use `v <<- c`.

There is however a trick to you linear algebra:

```
v %*% M = c_1
c_1 %*% M = c_2
c_2 = v %*% M %*% M = v %*% M^2
```